# Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml];

Tags: java, spring

I have this error and I have no idea what it can be, I leave some project classes

**POM.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SpringData</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringData</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>SpringData</name>
</project>
```

**ApplicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="dao"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="dominio" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>       
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BClientes" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Principal.java**

```
package principal;

import dao.ClienteRepositorio;
import dominio.Cliente;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        ClienteRepositorio clientes = (ClienteRepositorio)context.getBean("clienteRepositorio");

        Cliente cliente;

        Cliente cliente1 = new Cliente(1, "pwjuan", "Juan Alcaraz");
        Cliente cliente2 = new Cliente(2, "pwpedro", "Pedro Zamora");
        Cliente cliente3 = new Cliente(3, "pwluis", "Luis Valera");

        // Borramos todo, para no tener que ejecutar el script de la base cada vez
        for (Cliente c : clientes.findAll())
            clientes.delete(c);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Alta de clientes en proceso");
        clientes.save(cliente1);
        clientes.save(cliente2);
        clientes.save(cliente3);
       }
}
```

**Error:**

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at principal.Principal.main(Principal.java:12) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
>     ... 14 more
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 1.623s Finished at: Sun Jan 20 22:12:39 CET 2019 Final
>   Memory: 7M/245M
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (default-cli) on project SpringData: Command execution failed. Process
>   exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I have the project open in Eclipse and in NetBeans

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` means a version conflict in the imported jar files. You're mixing Spring versions: `spring-data-jpa` `1.6.1.RELEASE` requires `org.springframework` `3.2.9.RELEASE` but you're using a mix of `5.1.4.RELEASE` and `4.3.7.RELEASE`. Spring 3, 4, and 5 are not compatible with each other!!!

Comment: thanks, but still the same fault, I updated the post with the versions that I have put

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up Spring dependency versions. Worse, you are attempting to use three different major versions at the same time: `5.1.4.RELEASE`, `4.3.7.RELEASE`, `3.2.9.RELEASE`.

This setup is not supported, use the same version for all the Spring dependencies.

Based on whichever one you select, choose appropriate Spring Data version. For example [Spring Data 2.1.4.RELEASE uses Spring Framework 5.1.4.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#dependencies.spring-framework).

Comment: thanks, but still the same fault, I updated the post with the versions that I have put

Comment: `spring-data-commons` and `spring-data-jpa` are in different versions. Remove the exclude from `spring-data-jpa`, check the dependency versions with `mvn dependency:tree` to see they align. Not sure which Spring version is needed by `1.6.1`, please check it. There is no magic here, you are using incompatible JAR versions.

Comment: You can generate a new project with latest Spring Data JPA using https://start.spring.io/.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error. If you are using netbeans, then stop the current run process and start it again.